# Messages getting lost in Confluent Kafka Dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using Confluent kafka package in my recent c# project. I created a producer in the following way:

```
prodConfig = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx"};

foreach(msg in msglist){
    using(var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(prodConfig).Build()){
        producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, string> {Value = msg});
    }
}
```

But the issue is that some of my messages are not getting to the consumer. They are getting lost somewhere. However, if I use ***await*** with the producer then all the messages are getting delivered. How to deliver all my messages without await. (I have a single partition)

Comment: not so sure how it is done in C# but if you make use of asychnronous producer you usually should not forget to `flush` the producer after closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should use only a single `Producer` to send your `msgList`, because creating a new `Producer` for each message is really expensive.

What you could do, is use `Produce()` method with `Flush()`. With `Produce()` you will send messages asynchronously without waiting for a response. And then calling a `Flush()` will block until all in-flight messages are delivered.

```
var prodConfig = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx"};
using var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(prodConfig).Build();

foreach (var msg in msglist)
{
    producer.Produce(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = msg });
}

producer.Flush();
```

---

Without `await` or `Flush()` you might lose messages because your producer might be disposed before all the messages are delivered.